# it is possible to select only a portion of the current page url beyond what Dom can do

Tags: jquery, url

I've been looking everywhere for an answer to this but no luck.  I need to be able to only grab a specific portion of the pages url and then use it as a variable with jquery.  If it helps at all it's always going to be in the 2nd directory

```
www.domain.com/what i need to select/bla/bla/
```

Comment: The first-level directory name?

Answer (score 2):

You can [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string on the `/` character, and as you always want the "2nd directory", it's the element at index 1 of the resulting array:

```
var url = "www.domain.com/what i need to select/bla/bla/";
console.log(url.split("/")[1]); //Prints "what i need to select"
```

To actually get the current URL, you can use `window.location.href`:

`var url = window.location.href;`

Answer (score 2):

```
var path_parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
alert(path_parts[1]);
```

Comment: Or directly `window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]` to circumvent the parts-variable...